# Nodejs get two joined tables in rethinkdb

Tags: node.js, join, rethinkdb, reql

I'd like to join two tables and write get url with joined table (make get, post, delete on joined table).
I know how to do it with single table (e.g.):

```
 app.get('/employees', (req, res) => {
   r.table('employees').run(connection).then((cursor) => {
   // console.log(cursor)
   cursor.toArray().then((employees) => res.json(employees))
   })
 })
```

So i found in Rethinkdb documentation useful command:
https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/table-joins/

```
r.table("employees").eq_join("company_id", r.table("companies")).zip().run()
```

Returns the following result:

```
{
"id": "064058b6-cea9-4117-b92d-c911027a725a",
"name": "Jean-Luc Picard",
"company_id": "064058b6-cea9-4117-b92d-c911027a725a",
"rank": "captain",
"company": "Starfleet",
"type": "paramilitary"
```

}

How should I write my get code in nodejs? I don't know how can I name the merged table or how to call it.

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation:

```
If you use the zip command after join, 
the document from the right table will be merged into the left one.
```

I'd assume the table will still be named "employees"